# It is possible to compare the multiple regression models using AIC scores

Tags: r, linear-regression, lapply, mumin

It is possible to compare the multiple regression models using AIC scores, with the models ordered from best-supported to worst-supported?

Here is my code

```
 library(data.table)

 Regressions<- 
 data.table(February)[, 
                      .(Lm = lapply(.SD, function(x) summary(lm(February$PPNA ~ February$Acum1 + x)))),
                      .SDcols = 80:157]
```

Comment: yes it works, because i can fix the variables that i need, but i can't compare the regressions models using AIC scores. I want to ranking de models and i can do it, this is my problem

Answer (score 1):

We can  extract the `AIC` values and `order` based on the 'AIC' values

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(February)
dt1 <- dt[, .(Lm = lapply(.SD, function(x) lm(February$PPNA ~ February$Acum1 + x))),
          .SDcols = 80:157]
dt2 <-  dt1[, .(Lm = Lm[order(unlist(lapply(Lm, AIC)))])]
```

---

Or using a reproducible example

```
dt1 <- as.data.table(iris)[, .(Lm = lapply(.SD, function(x) 
          lm(iris$Petal.Length ~ iris$Species + x)))]
dt2 <-  dt1[, .(Lm = Lm[order(unlist(lapply(Lm, AIC)))])]
```

Comment: I try both and when you click on dt2 in the gloval environment it gives you the following extensive `list (coefficients = c (` (Intercept) `= ....` not an AIC value for each regression

Comment: @Pablo For me it is giving the `AIC`