# how to properly read a json file using pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

Currently I',m developing a application to analyze stack overflow questions. So I got the data as a json file from the stack API and used following codes to read the data in  json file as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_json("questions_sof.json")
df.head(3)
```

But the output gets received only with separated data like json file. But actually I wanted to add them in a table to analyze the data manually because is visually easy to handle.

```
questions
1   {'tags': ['r','loops','linear-regression'], 'owner': {'re...
2   {'tags': ['vb.net', 'winforms'], 'owner': {'re...
```

I tried few codes but couldn't able to figure it out a way to visualize data in a table in a proper way. Could you suggest me a correct way to show these data in a table or give some links to find out my self a answer for this question.
The json file contains a questions which were taken from stack overflow for analyze and I have given sample data of the json file.

json file content:

```
 {"questions":[
   {
     "tags": [
       "r",
       "loops",
       "linear-regression"
     ],
     "owner": {
       "reputation": 23,
       "user_id": 13106013,
       "user_type": "registered",
       "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7cfd118a3deb280317d603fe02271ed9?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
       "display_name": "Pablo",
       "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/13106013/pablo"
     },
     "is_answered": false,
     "view_count": 1,
     "answer_count": 0,
     "score": 0,
     "last_activity_date": 1586211687,
     "creation_date": 1586211687,
     "question_id": 61069878,
     "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069878/loop-for-multiple-linear-regression",
     "title": "Loop for multiple linear regression"
   },
   {
     "tags": [
       "vb.net",
       "winforms"
     ],
      "owner": {
       "reputation": 1,
       "user_id": 13242730,
       "user_type": "registered",
       "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/1499587313549122/picture?type=large",
       "display_name": "Ante Petrovi\u0107",
       "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/13242730/ante-petrovi%c4%87"
     },
     "is_answered": false,
     "view_count": 9,
     "answer_count": 0,
     "score": 0,
     "last_activity_date": 1586211684,
     "creation_date": 1586210993,
     "last_edit_date": 1586211684,
     "question_id": 61069743,
     "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069743/how-to-make-a-program-load-buttons-before-resizing-them",
     "title": "How to make a program load buttons before resizing them?"
   }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: please show your json file content

Comment: `df = pd.read_json('questions_sof.json', orient='records')`?

Comment: @Chris didn't works. still the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the output you are looking for?

```
import json

f = """{"questions":[
   {
     "tags": [
       "r",
       "loops",
       "linear-regression"
     ],
     "owner": {
       "reputation": 23,
       "user_id": 13106013,
       "user_type": "registered",
       "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7cfd118a3deb280317d603fe02271ed9?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
       "display_name": "Pablo",
       "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/13106013/pablo"
     },
     "is_answered": false,
     "view_count": 1,
     "answer_count": 0,
     "score": 0,
     "last_activity_date": 1586211687,
     "creation_date": 1586211687,
     "question_id": 61069878,
     "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069878/loop-for-multiple-linear-regression",
     "title": "Loop for multiple linear regression"
   },
   {
     "tags": [
       "vb.net",
       "winforms"
     ],
      "owner": {
       "reputation": 1,
       "user_id": 13242730,
       "user_type": "registered",
       "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/1499587313549122/picture?type=large",
       "display_name": "Ante Petrovi\u0107",
       "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/13242730/ante-petrovi%c4%87"
     },
     "is_answered": false,
     "view_count": 9,
     "answer_count": 0,
     "score": 0,
     "last_activity_date": 1586211684,
     "creation_date": 1586210993,
     "last_edit_date": 1586211684,
     "question_id": 61069743,
     "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069743/how-to-make-a-program-load-buttons-before-resizing-them",
     "title": "How to make a program load buttons before resizing them?"
   }
  ]
 }"""

# load json
j = json.loads(f)
# normalize json
df = pd.json_normalize(j['questions'])
```

Comment: No. I wants to represent them in a table instead as json data to visualize clearway.

Comment: What do you mean by table? I created a dataframe from the json...scroll down

Comment: pandas have't got a `json_normalize()` method. But I found the answer by importing relevant library to the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Anupa_sj I am not sure what version of pandas you are using but [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) exists